# How to make apache2 serve php-based projects with php7 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache2, php, 16.04, php7

Ubuntu 16.04 adds `libapache2-mod-php7.0` which messes up the `apache2` configuration for serving php-based projects (I'm formulating this so vaguely because I'd like to avoid dealing with source code for projects which are supposed to be setup out-of-the-box/without knowledge of internals, like `dokuwiki`).

Judging from the [official PHP 7 migration guide](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.incompatible.php) and errors like `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)` which didn't occur before and I didn't investigate further (see above) at least project I want to serve is incompatible with PHP 7 which make me have no interest in a PHP 7 setup and thus stick with PHP 5.

After `sudo a2dismod php7.0 && sudo a2enmod php5` I get a download offered.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

has always been in the site configuration which is for example

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:446 https

Alias /dokuwiki/ "/var/www/html/dokuwiki/"

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm doku.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

<Directory "/var/www/html/dokuwiki">
    Options None
    AllowOverride Limit

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost richtercloud.de:446 >
    ErrorLog /var/log/dokuwiki/dokuwiki.log
    SSLEngine On
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/dokuwiki"
    ServerName richtercloud.de
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Adding handler like

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
```

or

```
AddType text/html       php
```

(inspired by https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally) doesn't help.

It'd be good to change `https` to `http`, but all projects I serve are configured to build SSL connections interally, so that would mean a load of configuration changes which I'd like to avoid to the last moment.

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` contains

```
[Fri Mar 18 14:21:45.448248 2016] [core:notice] [pid 12155] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:45.449327 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12155] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:57.677426 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12732] AH01909: richtercloud.fritz.box:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:57.677519 2016] [:notice] [pid 12732] mod_qos(009): loaded MPM is 'prefork' but mod_qos should be used with MPM 'Worker' only.
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:57.677565 2016] [:warn] [pid 12732] mod_qos(009): mod_unique_id not available (mod_qos generates simple request id if required)
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:57.793923 2016] [:notice] [pid 12737] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 12737)
PHP Warning:  Module 'horde_lz4' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'igbinary' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'memcache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:58.010146 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12734] AH01909: richtercloud.fritz.box:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:58.010260 2016] [:notice] [pid 12734] mod_qos(009): loaded MPM is 'prefork' but mod_qos should be used with MPM 'Worker' only.
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:58.010309 2016] [:warn] [pid 12734] mod_qos(009): mod_unique_id not available (mod_qos generates simple request id if required)
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:58.025190 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12734] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Embperl/2.5.0 mod_auth_pgsql/2.0.3 mod_auth_gssapi/1.3.3 mod_auth_tkt/2.1.0 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_qos/11.21 mod_scgi/1.13 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.8.0 mod_defensible/1.2 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 18 14:22:58.025228 2016] [core:notice] [pid 12734] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

for every (re)start which doesn't seem problematic.

The `ErrorLog` of the `VirtualHost` of the `dokuwiki` example above contained

```
[Fri Mar 18 03:07:49.551221 2016] [proxy:warn] [pid 4306] [client 192.168.179.52:34298] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /doku.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

and I have no idea how I got rid of it, but it didn't change anything, anyway.

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -M 
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 auth_pgsql_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 apreq_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_gssapi_module (shared)
 auth_plain_module (shared)
 auth_tkt_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 defensible_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 encoding_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fastcgi_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 geoip_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 perl_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 qos_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 scgi_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 xsendfile_module (shared)
 embperl_module (shared)
```

I know that's a development version based question, but it might as well get answered now rather than after the first hours of the release when a bunch of people will experience this issue.

Comment: You are around for a long time and should know that this is a wrong place to report this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confused by mods and confs and sites and `.htaccess` and ... Apparently it's possible to have confs for `php5-cgi` and `php7.0-fpm` enabled which can be fixed with

```
sudo a2disconf php7.0-fpm 
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```